# How can I filter with both NOT and OR in minimatch patterns?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, glob, minimatch

We're using TFS 2017 and the Copy File build step to copy specific files of our build result to another directory. Specifically, we only want *.dll and *.exe copied, but no *.Tests.dll or *.resources.dll.

The build step support minimatch patterns to filter files, but I can't get it to apply BOTH filters.

The pattern looks like this:

```
bin\**\?(*.exe|*.dll)
bin\**\!(*.Tests.dll|*.resources.dll)
```

The folder content for example is:

```
bin\Yes.dll
bin\Yes.exe
bin\No.Tests.dll
bin\No\Some.resources.dll
```

It seems that the patterns are applied sequentially, so they both work individually, but not after another.

I tried something like

```
bin\**\?(*.exe|*.dll)!(*.Tests.dll|*.resources.dll)
```

But that didn't work either and filtered nothing. Can I combine these into a single filter somehow? The [docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/file-matching-patterns) don't cover that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, seems you actually can just put the expressions directly after another, the filters just have to be more strict. This works, but I have still no clue why:

```
bin\**\!(*.Tests.dll|*.resources.dll|*.pdb|*.xml|*.manifest)?(*.exe|*.dll)
```